# TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object Dask compute

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I'm trying to do multiprocessing using dask. I have a function which has to run for 10000 files and will generate files as an output. Function is taking files from S3 bucket as an input and is working with another file inside from S3 with similar date and time. And I'm doing everything in JupyterLab

So here's my function:

```
def get_temp(file, name):
    
    d=[name[0:4],name[4:6],name[6:8],name[9:11],name[11:13]] 
    f_zip = gzip.decompress(file)
    
    yr=d[0]
    mo=d[1]
    da=d[2]
    hr=d[3]
    mn=d[4]
    
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)

    period = pd.Period(str(yr)+str('-')+str(mo)+str('-')+str(da), freq='D')
    # period.dayofyear
    dy=period.dayofyear

    cc=[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]  #look at the IR channels only for now
    dat = xr.open_dataset(f_zip)
    dd=dat[['recNum','trackLat','trackLon', 'temp']]
    dd=dd.to_dataframe()
    dd = dd.dropna()
    dd['num'] = np.arange(len(dd))
    
    l=dd.where((dd.trackLat>-50.0) & (dd.trackLat<50.0) & (dd.trackLon>-110.0) & (dd.trackLon<10.0))
    l = l.dropna() 
    l.reset_index()
    
    dy="{0:0=3d}".format(dy)
    
#opening goes data from S3
    F=xr.open_dataset(fs.open(fs.glob('s3://noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadF/'+str(yr)+'/'+str(dy)+'/'+str(hr)+'/'+'OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C07'+'*')[int(mn)//15]))
    
#Converting Lat lon to radiance
    req=F['goes_imager_projection'].semi_major_axis
    oneovf=F['goes_imager_projection'].inverse_flattening
    rpol=F['goes_imager_projection'].semi_minor_axis 
    e = 0.0818191910435
    sat_h=F['goes_imager_projection'].perspective_point_height

    H=req+sat_h
    gc=np.deg2rad(F['goes_imager_projection'].longitude_of_projection_origin)

    phi=np.deg2rad(l.trackLat.values)
    gam=np.deg2rad(l.trackLon.values)

    phic=np.arctan((rpol**2/req**2)*np.tan(phi))
    rc=rpol/np.sqrt((1-e**2*np.cos(phic)**2))
    sx=H-rc*np.cos(phic)*np.cos(gam-gc)
    sy=-rc*np.cos(phic)*np.sin(gam-gc)
    sz=rc*np.sin(phic)

    yy=np.arctan(sz/sx)
    xx=np.arcsin(-sy/(np.sqrt(sx**2+sy**2+sz**2)))
    
    for i in range(len(xx)):
        for c in range(len(ch):
            ch="{0:0=2d}".format(cc[c])
            
            F1=xr.open_dataset(fs.open(fs.glob('s3://noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadF/'+str(yr)+'/'+str(dy)+'/'+str(hr)+'/'+'OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C'+ch+'*')[0]))

            F2=xr.open_dataset(fs.open(fs.glob('s3://noaa-goes16/ABI-L1b-RadF/'+str(yr)+'/'+str(dy)+'/'+str("{0:0=2d}".format(hr))+'/'+'OR_ABI-L1b-RadF-M3C'+ch+'*')[-1]))
           
            G1 = F1.where((F1.x >= (xx[i]-0.005)) & (F1.x <= (xx[i]+0.005)) & (F1.y >= (yy[i]-0.005)) & (F1.y <= (yy[i]+0.005)), drop=True)
            G2 = F2.where((F2.x >= (xx[i]-0.005)) & (F2.x <= (xx[i]+0.005)) & (F2.y >= (yy[i]-0.005)) & (F2.y <= (yy[i]+0.005)), drop=True)
            
            G = xr.concat([G1, G2], dim  = 'time')
            G = G.assign_coords(channel=(ch))
            
            if c == 0:
                T = G    
            else:
                T = xr.concat([T, G], dim = 'channel')
                
        T = T.assign_coords(temp=(str(l['temp'][i])))
        print(l.iloc[i]['num'])
        path = name+'_'+str(int(l.iloc[i]['num']))+'.nc'          
        T.to_netcdf(path)
    
#zipping the file
        with zipfile.ZipFile(name+'_'+str(int(l.iloc[i]['num']))+'.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            zf.write(path, arcname=str(name+'_'+str(int(l.iloc[i]['num']))+'.nc'))

 # Storing it to S3    
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET).upload_file(path[:-3]+'.zip', "Output/" + path[:-3]+'.zip')
```

Here's I'm calling data from S3:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

s3client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    region_name='us-east-1'
)

bucketname = s3.Bucket('temp')
filedata = []
keys = []
names = []

for my_bucket_object in bucketname.objects.all():
    keys.append(my_bucket_object.key)
    
for i in range(1, 21):
    fileobj = s3client.get_object(
        Bucket='temp',
        Key=(keys[i]))

    filedata.append(fileobj['Body'].read())
    names.append(keys[i][10:-3])
```

Initially, I'm just trying to run 20 files for testing purposes.

Here's I'm creating dask delayed and compute function:

```
temp_files = []

for i in range(20):
    s3_ds = dask.delayed(get_temp)(filedata[i], names[i])
    temp_files.append(s3_ds)

temp_files = dask.compute(*temp_files)
```

Here's full log of error:

```
distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to serialize <function get_temp at 0x7f20a9cb8550>. Exception: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py in dumps_function(func)
   3319         with _cache_lock:
-> 3320             result = cache_dumps[func]
   3321     except KeyError:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1572     def __getitem__(self, key):
-> 1573         value = super().__getitem__(key)
   1574         self.data.move_to_end(key)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1009             return self.__class__.__missing__(self, key)
-> 1010         raise KeyError(key)
   1011     def __setitem__(self, key, item): self.data[key] = item

KeyError: <function get_temp at 0x7f20a9cb8550>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py in dumps(x, buffer_callback, protocol)
     52                 buffers.clear()
---> 53                 result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
     54         elif not _always_use_pickle_for(x) and b"__main__" in result:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     72             )
---> 73             cp.dump(obj)
     74             return file.getvalue()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dump(self, obj)
    562         try:
--> 563             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    564         except RuntimeError as e:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-fa46004f5919> in <module>
----> 1 temp_files = dask.compute(*temp_files)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    450         postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
    451 
--> 452     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    453     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    454 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in get(self, dsk, keys, restrictions, loose_restrictions, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   2703         Client.compute: Compute asynchronous collections
   2704         """
-> 2705         futures = self._graph_to_futures(
   2706             dsk,
   2707             keys=set(flatten([keys])),

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _graph_to_futures(self, dsk, keys, restrictions, loose_restrictions, priority, user_priority, resources, retries, fifo_timeout, actors)
   2639                 {
   2640                     "op": "update-graph",
-> 2641                     "tasks": valmap(dumps_task, dsk),
   2642                     "dependencies": dependencies,
   2643                     "keys": list(map(tokey, keys)),

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx in cytoolz.dicttoolz.valmap()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx in cytoolz.dicttoolz.valmap()

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py in dumps_task(task)
   3356             return d
   3357         elif not any(map(_maybe_complex, task[1:])):
-> 3358             return {"function": dumps_function(task[0]), "args": warn_dumps(task[1:])}
   3359     return to_serialize(task)
   3360 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py in dumps_function(func)
   3320             result = cache_dumps[func]
   3321     except KeyError:
-> 3322         result = pickle.dumps(func, protocol=4)
   3323         if len(result) < 100000:
   3324             with _cache_lock:

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py in dumps(x, buffer_callback, protocol)
     58         try:
     59             buffers.clear()
---> 60             result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
     61         except Exception as e:
     62             logger.info("Failed to serialize %s. Exception: %s", x, e)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     71                 file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72             )
---> 73             cp.dump(obj)
     74             return file.getvalue()
     75 

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dump(self, obj)
    561     def dump(self, obj):
    562         try:
--> 563             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    564         except RuntimeError as e:
    565             if "recursion" in e.args[0]:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Can someone help me here and tell me what I'm doing wrong. And apart from Dask is there any other way for parallel processing?

So I figured out only when I'm uploading file to S3 bucket it's throwing that error, otherwise it's working fine. But If I'm not saving files in S3, I'm not able to figure out where the files are getting stored. When I'm running on dask it's saving file somewhere where I'm not able to find it. I'm running my code in Jupyterlab and there's nothing getting save in any directory.

Comment: Please try to create a *minimal* example which still shows the problem. There is far too much code here for us to try to parse.

Comment: @mdurant hey please check the edited ques. So when I'm uploading files on S3 it's giving error, otherwise it's working fine.

Comment: It's too much and not enough code at the same time -- it is missing required `import` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken some time to parse your code.

In the large function, you use `s3fs` to interact with your cloud storage, and this works well with xarray.

However, in your main code, you use `boto3` to list and open S3 files. These files retain a reference to the client object, which maintains a connection pool. That is the thing that cannot be pickled.

`s3fs` is designed to work with Dask, and ensures the picklebility of the filesystem instances and OpenFile objects. Since you already use it in one part, I would recommend using `s3fs` throughout (but I am, of course biased, since I am the main author).

Alternatively, you could pass just the file names (as strings), and not open anything until within the worker function. This would be "best practice" - you should load data in worker tasks, rather than loading in the client and passing the data.

Comment: @mudrant hey it did work for me, thank you so much sir! :)